# How to flatten or combine member names into one list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example if I have something like so:

```
var Constants = {
  scope:{
    namespaceA: { A_X: "TEST_AX" , A_Y: "TEST_AY" },
    namespaceN: { N_X: "TEST_NX" , N_Y: "TEST_NY" }
  }
  _mapping: [],
  getMapping: function(){...}
}

var flattenList = flatten(Constants.scope); //returns ["TEST_AX","TEST_AY","TEST_NX","TEST_NY"]
var anotherWayFlattened = flatten(Constants.scope.namespaceA,Constants.scope.namespaceB); //returns same result as above
```

EDIT: one way would be to iterate over the scope via for-each loop but I was looking for something more elegent?

DOUBLE EDIT: ok I just whipped something up like so:

```
var flattenedList = (function(list){
    var flatList = []
    $.each(list,function(i,items){
        for(var p in items) flatList.push(items[p]);
    })
    return flatList;
})([Constants.scope.namespaceA,Constants.scope.namespaceB]);
```

but was wondering if we can avoid passing in the particular property and just pass in Constants and search for  the list of namespaces

Comment: Is this supposed to work with just the one or two levels demonstrated or work to arbitrary depths?

Comment: upto 2 levels would be fine

Comment: Daniel's question has become the default first question comment for anything that has not demonstrated any effort.  Have you tried this?  Has anything come close?  What have been the stumbling blocks?

Comment: @everyone: ok didn't know, its cool, I double edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[Constants.scope.namespaceA,Constants.scope.namespaceB]`

I'm wondering why you pass the sub-objects explicitly in an array. Why not just pass the whole `Constants.scope` object?

```
var flattenedList = (function(obj){
    var flatList = []
    for (var prop in obj) {
        var items = obj[prop];
        for (var p in items)
            flatList.push(items[p]);
    }
    return flatList;
})(Constants.scope);
```

---

From your comment it looks like you wanted this:

```
var flattenedList = (function(obj, test){
    var flatList = []
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (!test(prop))
            continue;
        var items = obj[prop];
        for (var p in items)
            flatList.push(items[p]);
    }
    return flatList;
})(Constants, function(name) {
    return name.substr(0, 9) == "namespace";
    // or maybe
    return /^namespace[A-Z]$/.test(name);
});
```

Comment: yea sorry about that, in the original example I started out with the structure `Constants.scope.namespaceA` but in my code its just more akin to `Constants.namespaceA, Constants.namespaceB`. Is there a way to ignore the other properties such as `Constants._mappings`, and be able to pass in the whole `Constants` object and just  reject anything that is not namespaceA, namespaceB, namespaceN?

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to recurse to any (non cyclical!) depth, you could do this :

```
function flattenList(list, accumulator){
    accumulator = accumulator || [];
    for(var p in list){
        if(list.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if(typeof list[p] === "string") {
                accumulator.push(list[p]);
            } else if(typeof list[p] === "object") { // this is not a reliable test!
                flattenList(list[p], accumulator);
            }
        }
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

This code makes a number of assumptions - we only have strings at the end of our objects etc. Alternatively, if you know the depth in advance, your current solution can be optimized by using concat :

```
var flattenedList = (function(list){
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], list);
})([Constants.scope.namespaceA,Constants.scope.namespaceB]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that allows for deeper nesting.  I know that wasn't part of the goals, but I found it a more interesting problem.  :-)

```
var flatten = (function() {
    var toString = Object.prototype.toString, slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    var flatten = function(input, output) {
        var value;
        output = (toString.call(output) == "[object Array]") ? output : [];
        for (name in input) {if (input.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            value = input[name];
            if (toString.call(value) == "[object Object]") {
                flatten(value, output);
            } else {
                output.push(value);
            }
        }};
        return output;
    };
    var merge = function(first, second) {
        return first.concat(second);
    }

    return function() {
        return slice.call(arguments).map(flatten).reduce(merge);
    };
}());
```

This allows either approach:

```
flatten(Constants.scope);
flatten(Constants.scope.namespaceA, Constants.scope.namespaceN);
```

You can pass in as many separate arguments as you like, or one argument.  They'll all be searched to arbitrary depths.

For some environments, you might have to shim `Array.prototype` functions `map` and `reduce`.